# Flutter loading screen between routes

Tags: javascript, android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that has a homepage and an article page.
The homepage displays multiple articles you can click and be shown the article page with that article. When navigated to the article page I use a call in the initState of the article page to load an interstitial.
I'm using Named Routing to navigate between the pages.

What I want to achieve is that when a user clicks on an article on the homepage, he is navigated to the article page in the background while a full screen overlay with a loading animation. The article page should be open in the background so it can be rendered with server images and text before the client sees it.
After the overlay comes up I will call the interstitial function. If there is an interstitial, it will come up on top of the app, the overlay will be removed and when the user closes the interstitial he will see the article page with the content preloaded.
If there isn't an interstitial, after X amount of seconds the overlay will be removed and the user will again see the preloaded article page.

Can anyone help me achieve that?

Thanks !

Comment: StackOverflow is for users to help you with your coding issues. Not a coding service. Please read the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

You are asking a very general state management question. I will provide an answer that uses a boolean and `setState()` to indicate loading state. This is the most primitive way to handle states. It will get messier once you have more states/pages. You should read further articles in [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt) and select a state management solution.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: ScreenHome(),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenHomeState createState() => _ScreenHomeState();
}

class _ScreenHomeState extends State<ScreenHome> {
  List<int>   _ids = [3,75,776,23];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _ids.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ArticlePage(_ids[index])),
                );
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Text(_ids[index].toString()),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ArticlePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int articleId;

  const ArticlePage(this.articleId, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ArticlePageState createState() => _ArticlePageState();
}

class _ArticlePageState extends State<ArticlePage> {
  bool _loading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child:
            _loading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text("Article id: ${widget.articleId}"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have done exactly that. What I'm trying to achieve is a loading screen on top of the screen that is currently loading in the background, so images on the back screen will be able to load before I remove the loading screen. Your solution will only start rendering the content after I remove the loading indicator.

Comment: You can use `Stack` and put loading UI on top of main UI, you can hide the loading widget after the tasks done.

Comment: I don't see any routes used as asked in the question